# Quicksteps - bigger view on a Ribbon

Tags: outlook, ribbon

i am using Outlook Quick Steps and I have roughly 40 of them.
Just wanted to know if there is as option to expand the view somehow.
If i need to go through 200 emails per day that could be quite usefull.

Comment: You may consider creating a VBA macro instead. Then you can assign QAT buttons to VBA functions.

Comment: How do I do it ? how can i assing existing QAT to VBA button ? Honestly do not want to write any kind of code

Comment: Outlook doesn't allow customizing the ribbon UI from VBA macros. You need to develop a COM add-in for that. The best what you could do is to develop a VBA to automate tasks/routine in Outlook and then manually assign your VBA sub to the ribbon button.